# Как вставить последнюю часть ссылки в href?

Tags: javascript

Допустим, мы на странице адрес которой `yandex.ru/maps/moscow/search`
Как взять последний кусок `/search` и вставить его в 
`<input value="/something/(вставить_сюда)">`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так например

**UPD** данные с адресной строки

```js
//const link = 'andex.ru/maps/moscow/search';
const link = window.location.href;

const val = link.split('/').pop();

const inp = document.querySelector('input');

inp.value = `/something/${val}`;
```

```html
<input value="" />
```

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, а можно не привязываться к конкретному адресу а брать его из адресной строки?

Comment: @QuickBrownFox используйте `window.location.href`

Comment: Пожалуйста, покажите на примере, если не трудно, и ответ - Ваш. Спасибо!

Comment: @QuickBrownFox дополнил ответ

Answer (score 2):

**Один из вариантов:**

```
let str = window.location.href,
    match = str.match(/\/([^/]+)$/);

res = match[1];
```

**Второй:**

```
  let str = window.location.href;
   res = str.split('/').pop());
```

**Вставка в INPUT:**

```
const selector = document.querySelector('input');
if(selector)
    inp.value+=res;
```

**Полный пример:**

```
  let url = window.location.href;
      res = str.split('/').pop());
      selector = document.querySelector('input');

  if(selector)
      inp.value+=res;
```

Comment: Подскажите, а можно как-либо сделать без привязки к конкретному адресу?

Comment: И вставить именно в определенное место, как в формуле в посте? Спасибо!

Comment: @QuickBrownFox, к адресу привязки нет. Это просто как пример. Всегда будет браться последняя часть ссылки. Если Вам нужное другое, уточните